# How to know what part of the file is currently displayed in a window?

Tags: window

Essentially, is there a function in Emacs like

text-currently-displayed-in-window --> returns two integer

The integers represents the position interval that is currently being displayed on screen in the selected window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `window-start` and `window-end` to get the buffer positions of the portion that is visible in a window.

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly it.